# Terminating an infinite loop

Tags: bash, signals

I have a command that I want to have run again automatically each time it terminates, so I ran something like this:

```
while [ 1 ]; do COMMAND; done;
```

but if I can't stop the loop with <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> as that just kills `COMMAND` and not the entire loop.

How would I achieve something similar but which I can stop without having to close the terminal?

Comment: If I'm in bash I just use Ctrl-Z to stop the job and then "kill %1" to kill it.

Comment: Just wait... Linus was quoted as saying: *“We all know Linux is great... it does infinite loops in 5 seconds.”* -- so really... just wait a few more seconds, it should complete.

Comment: @PaulCager worked for me too! Why does it work where Ctrl-C does not?

Comment: @cirosantilli it kills the outer job (the bash "wrapper"). In some situations, it won't immediately kill the "COMMAND", for instance, if you background it, it may sneak past alive even if it's parent is dead. But the loop is dead, and that's the important part.

Comment: @orion: I don't agree, but I don't exactly know how to proove: Ctrl-C is swallowed by the COMMAND inside the loop, so the COMMAND is interrupted and the outer loop will continue. To kill the outer loop I usually add a sleep command and press CTRL-C some more times: `while :; do LONGTIME_COMMAND; sleep 1; done`. Please notice: the colon behind `while` is interpreded as TRUE, so this is an endless loop.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Check the exit status of the command.  If the command was terminated by a signal the exit code will be 128 + the signal number.  From the [GNU online documentation for bash](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Exit-Status):

> For the shell’s purposes, a command which exits with a zero exit status has succeeded. A non-zero exit status indicates failure. This seemingly counter-intuitive scheme is used so there is one well-defined way to indicate success and a variety of ways to indicate various failure modes. When a command terminates on a fatal signal whose number is N, Bash uses the value 128+N as the exit status.

[POSIX also specifies](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_08_02) that the value of a command that terminated by a signal is greater than 128, but does not seem to specify its exact value like GNU does:

> The exit status of a command that terminated because it received a signal shall be reported as greater than 128.

For example if you interrupt a command with control-C the exit code will be 130, because SIGINT is signal 2 on Unix systems.  So:

```
while [ 1 ]; do COMMAND; test $? -gt 128 && break; done
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that this is not guaranteed, in fact, many applications will not do this.

Answer (score 66):

You can stop and put your job in background while it's running using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>. Then you can kill your job with:

```
$ kill %1
```

Where [1] is your job number.

Comment: See also [this answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48465/26952) for explanations and more.

Answer (score 26):

I would say it might be best to put your infinite loop in a script and handle signals there. Here's a *basic starting point*.  I'm sure you'll want to modify it to suit.  The script uses `trap` to catch <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> (or `SIGTERM`), kills off the command (I've used `sleep` here as a test) and exits.

```
cleanup ()
{
kill -s SIGTERM $!
exit 0
}

trap cleanup SIGINT SIGTERM

while [ 1 ]
do
    sleep 60 &
    wait $!
done
```

Comment: Nice. Here's how I used this tip to make an autorestarting netcat wrapper: `trap "exit 0" SIGINT SIGTERM; while true; do netcat -l -p 3000; done`

Comment: if you add this `trap` approach to the same (bash) script with the infinite loop to be killed, use `$$` instead of `$!` (see [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/internalvariables.html))

Answer (score 16):

I generally just hold down <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>. Sooner or later it'll register between `COMMAND`'s and thus terminate the `while` loop. Maybe there is a better way.

Comment: Not sure why, but it fails for certain COMMANDs like `paplay` on a 1s file.

Comment: That's the brute force of all solutions here. :/

Answer (score 12):

If you run bash with `-e` it will exit on any error conditions:

```
#!/bin/bash -e
false # returns 1
echo This won't be printed
```

Comment: The first line here is by far the simplest solution for a trivial script that you don't wish to spend too much time on!

Answer (score 11):

Why not simply,

```
while [ 1 ]; do COMMAND || break; done;
```

Or when used in a script,

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1 ]; do
  # ctrl+c terminates COMMAND and exits the while loop
  # (assuming COMMAND responds to ctrl+c)
  COMMAND || break
done;
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. But wouldn't this only work if COMMAND always returns a success exit status?

Comment: Yes @howardh, that's correct.

Answer (score 4):

I prefer another solution:

```
touch .runcmd; while [ -f ".runcmd" ]; do COMMAND; sleep 1; done
```

In order to kill the loop, just do:

```
rm .runcmd && kill `pidof COMMAND`
```

Answer (score 4):

What works reasonably well for me is:

```bsh
while sleep 1; do COMMAND; done
```

This works because sleep 1 sticks around for a while and if it gets ctrl+c it return with non zero and the loop will terminate.

Comment: +1, sleep time can also be reduced to `0.5` or `0.1`: `while sleep 0.1; do COMMAND; done`

Answer (score 3):

1. You can always kill a process using its PID, there's no need to close your terminal
2. If you want to run something in an infinite loop like a daemon then you'd best put it in the background
3. `while :` will create an infinite loop and saves you writing the `[ 1 ]`

   ```
   while :; do COMMAND; done &
   ```

This will print the PID.  If you exit your prompt using `ctrl+d` then the background job won't quit, and you can later kill the job from anywhere using `kill PID`

If you lose track of your PID, you can use `pstree -pa $USER` or `pgrep -fl '.*PROCESS.*'` to help you find it

Answer (score 1):

I like this one-liner for this kind of problem:

```
while $COMMAND ; do : ; done
```

As long as `$COMMAND` terminates successfully, it will be run again.  If it fails or is terminated by signal, the loop will end.

Comment: Thank you for using the human-readable `if`-`then` syntax rather than the machine-language  `||`  or  `&&`.  You have proved that you are not a robot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `trap` -

```sh
exit_()
{
    exit
}

while true
do
    echo 'running..'
    trap exit_ int
done
```