# How to stop the loop bash script in terminal?

Tags: bash, signals, trap

For example,

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    sl
done
```

How to terminate this bash script?

Comment: Give more details. Do you want to stop it interactively or programmatically?

Comment: you can press `ctrl-c` to send the `SIGINT` signal (in most shells) or you can press `ctrl-z` that sends the `SIGTSTP` signal (in most shells). In the case you pressed `ctrl-z` the related process isn't killed but paused. You can resume it with `fg` (at least in `bash`)

Comment: No, it doesn't work!

Comment: @manatwork interactively!!

Comment: Use user1146332's suggestion but raise the violence level. I mean, press Ctrl-C and keep it pressed. After a few seconds usually the `while` which keeps starting newer and newer `sl` instances will also receive a `SIGINT`.

Comment: The problem is not the script, but the `sl` command which I believe is an annoing command for those who misspell `ls`, showing a train passing slowly by. As far as I know it traps the `SIGINT` signal and must be killed with `SIGKILL`.

Comment: @htor, that's interesting. Which package contains it?

Comment: @manatwork: `sl`

Comment: A debian package is [here](http://packages.debian.org/squeeze/sl). Anyway, its totally useless and annoing (being a victim of this treachery at univ.).

Comment: Thanks. Not packed for my distro, that's why I not knew/found it. (I think I will not file a request for it.)

Comment: Some people seem to like `sl`, as long as they're [four years old](http://changelog.complete.org/archives/5451-jacob-4-years-old-and-troubleshooting-pcs) :)

Comment: that's hilarious and evil.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The program `sl` purposely ignores `SIGINT`, which is what gets sent when you press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>.  So, firstly, you'll need to tell `sl` not to ignore `SIGINT` by adding the `-e` argument.

If you try this, you'll notice that you can stop each individual `sl`, but they still repeat.  You need to tell `bash` to exit after `SIGINT` as well.  You can do this by putting a `trap "exit" INT` before the loop.

```
#!/bin/bash
trap "exit" INT
while :
do
    sl -e
done
```

Comment: I don't have it installed to check, but you might also be able to kill it with SIGQUIT from Ctrl-\

Answer (score 158):

1. press `Ctrl-Z` to suspend the script
2. `kill %%`

The `%%` tells the bash built-in `kill` that you want to send a signal (SIGTERM by default) to the most recently suspended background job in the current shell, not to a process-id.

You can also specify jobs by number or by name.   e.g. when you suspend a job with ^Z, bash will tell you what its job number is with something like `[n]+  Stopped`, where the `n` inside the square brackets is the job number.

For more info on job control and on killing jobs, run `help jobs`, `help fg`, `help bg`, and `help kill` in bash, and search for `JOB CONTROL` (all caps) or `jobspec` in the bash man page.

e.g.

```
$ ./killme.sh 
./killme.sh: line 4: sl: command not found
./killme.sh: line 4: sl: command not found
./killme.sh: line 4: sl: command not found
./killme.sh: line 4: sl: command not found
./killme.sh: line 4: sl: command not found
...
...
...
./killme.sh: line 4: sl: command not found
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 ./killme.sh
$ kill %%
$ 
[1]+  Terminated              ./killme.sh
```

In this example, the job's number was 1, so `kill %1` would have worked the same as `kill %%`

(NOTE: I don't have `sl` installed so the output is just "command not found".   in your case, you'll get whatever output sl produces.  it's not important - the `^Z` suspend and `kill %%` will work the same)

Comment: BTW, for rapidly executing loops like this, ^Z can be a more reliable way to kill the process than ^C.  ^C will be sent to the program (`sl`) being run in the loop, but the script will keep running...and start another `sl`.  If you press ^C a few times really fast, you may get to kill both the `sl` and the script (if neither of them trap SIGINT).   ^Z will suspend the script almost immediately (immediately if you don't count buffered output that is still being printed to your terminal), so you can kill it with `kill %%`

Comment: Exactly! I have to say "`sl` is a fun program". This time, it fun me again! @_@

Comment: Only answer that seems to work also when the loop isn't called from a script but from command line directly.

Comment: How did you find out about `%%` ? I see no mention of it in the `kill` manpage. Nor anything about background processes.

Comment: @DrewChapin I can't remember when/where I found out about it - just something I've known "since forever".  The bash man page (search for *jobspec*) says: `The symbols %% and %+ refer to the shell's notion of the current job, which is the last job stopped while it was in the foreground or started in  the  background.  The previous job may be referenced using %-.  If there is only a single job, %+ and %- can both be used to refer to that job`

Comment: @DrewChapin `%%` is also specified as *the current job* in the POSIX standard: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_204

Answer (score 16):

If you want ctrl+c to stop the loop, but not terminate the script, you can  place `|| break` after whatever command you're running. As long as the program you're running terminates on ctrl+c, this works great.

```
#!/bin/bash
while :
do
    # ctrl+c terminates sl, but not the shell script
    sl -e || break
done
```

If you're in nested loop, you can use "break 2" to get out of two levels, etc.

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way is to issue the `QUIT` signal, which is usually attached to `Control-Backslash`.

When you see the train, hit Control-\

Comment: That's a new one on me. More details at https://askubuntu.com/questions/341189/why-does-ctrl-backslash-not-kill-the-process-any-more

Answer (score 5):

You can terminate that script by pressing Ctrl+C from terminal where you started this script. Of course this script must run in foreground so you are able to stop it by Ctrl+C.

Or you can find PID (Process ID) of that script in other opened terminal by:

```
ps -ef | grep <name_of_the_script>
kill -9 <pid_of_your_running_script>
```

Both ways should do the trick your are asking for.

Comment: It can't be terminated by Ctrl+C from terminal. So I have to kill it by ps or top. I just want to know how to kill it directly!

Answer (score 4):

Another way to terminate the entire script would be to background the `sl` command and then trap signal `INT` to kill the entire process group of the script with signal `HUP`.

```
#!/bin/bash

trap 'trap - INT; kill -s HUP -- -$$' INT
#trap 'trap - INT; kill -s HUP 0' INT

while :
do
   sl & wait
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You can `kill` the `pid` of shell (bash).
I just tried and it works.
Because I cannot see the process from `ps -ef` (the job that we run in the looping script).

Answer (score -1):

Put at the end of script:

```
kill -9 $PPID
exit
```

Comment: This won’t help, the question effectively asks about exiting the loop; adding something after the loop won’t make a difference.

Answer (score -2):

```
while [ true ] 
do

  #check if script is running
  ps | grep script_name.sh | grep -v grep >/dev/null 2>&1

  if [ "$!" != "0" ] ; then
    break
  else

    kill -9 ` ps -ef | grep script_name.sh | cut -d "a" -f 1` 
    echo "kill -9 `get script PID`"

  fi

done
```

this should help.

Comment: Why do you think the PID of the last background command will ever be 0?

Answer (score -2):

use `set -e` to exit from failure.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
set -e
while :
do
    sl
done
```

Comment: That won't work. `sl` doesn't die with ctrl+c.

Answer (score -2):

The killing thing is awful, because you never now, if the script has to run twice. AND your exit code is wrong.

```
while [ something ]; do

 if [ somethingelse ]; then
   echo shut down script with exit code 0
   exit 0
 fi
done

echo something else not happend
exit 2 # Return val important for example for monitoring
```

No working.
Solution = use perl. 
while opens own bash