# How to catch a signal in command line?

Tags: shell, shell-script, signals

I asked this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153905/how-to-make-an-infinitely-executing-command-kill-itself-when-certain-conditions). `SIGPIPE` signal is generated to stop the execution of the command as told in the answer.

But how do I capture this signal and gracefully terminate the command? The command exits with an error saying that it is a broken pipe.

> [ERROR] [Errno 32] Broken pipe

is the error message displayed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, the only way to "catch" a signal like this is to use the `trap` command. Which you specifically setup an action (function or command(s)) to run when a particular signal is received.

#### Example

```
#!/bin/bash


cleanup () {
    ...do cleanup tasks & exit...
}

trap "cleanup" SIGPIPE

### MAIN part of script
```

This approach could just as easily be in a single one-liner vs. a script. The "function" that is called, `cleanup`, when `SIGPIPE` is seen could just as easily be a elaborate one-liner too.

```
$ trap "cmd1; cmd2; cmd3;" SIGPIPE
```

If you look back at the original question you linked to: [Terminating an infinite loop](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42287/terminating-an-infinite-loop), you'll notice that this approach is even represented there as well.

Comment: sorry, didn't see that answer. Thank you

Comment: @user2555595 - NP. If you don't know what traps are, they're easy to disregard. I only learned about how to actual use them myself, this past month 8-).

Comment: I tried that code, and put `yes | head -n 10` in the "MAIN part". But the cleanup will be never called. Besides, if you call the script like `(trap '' SIGPIPE; ./script)` in shell the broken pipe message will be shown. Putting `set -o pipefail` above the pipe affects to the exit status of the pipeline.